# Missed optimization in clang only on powers of two

Tags: c++, x86, clang, compiler-optimization

When compiling with -Ofast, clang correctly deduces that the following function will always return 0.

```
int zero(bool b) {
    const int x = 5;
    return (x * b) + (-x * b);
}
```

compiles to

```
zero(bool):                               # @zero(bool)
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

However, if I change the constant to be any power of two (except 1 or 0), clang no longer makes the same deduction

```
int zero(bool b) {
    const int x = 8;
    return (x * b) + (-x * b);
}
```

compiles to

```
zero(bool):                               # @zero(bool)
        mov     eax, edi
        shl     eax, 3
        xor     dil, 1
        movzx   ecx, dil
        lea     eax, [rax + 8*rcx]
        add     eax, -8
        ret
```

[The code compiled with compiler explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/rZhicR)

If I change the function parameter to be anything bigger (short, int, long) the optimization is correctly made.

What causes this weird edge case?

Comment: Log a bug for it?

Comment: And if the constant is changed to a parameter passed to the function, code is correct. Weird, indeed.

Comment: @JVApen I've been meaning to get around to it.

Comment: @spyr03 Even if you can get around it, logging a bug for it makes sense.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Good observation, I didn't notice that. It also works again at 2**31, even preventing overflow by making the constant unsigned.

Comment: Good bug report. Unnecessary Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with clang-trunk. Seems to be changed/fixed.

Comment: @WernerHenze Thats good, thanks for checking. The bug I opened was marked as fixed. https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42257

Comment: @spyr03 It would be good to either delete the question or to add an answer and to accept it. Can you please do so!? Thanks.

Comment: @WernerHenze I disagree. The question of "Why did this happen" has as of yet not been answered.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any bug fix reports for this particular issue but seen from the asm output, it looks like an optimization ordering problem for me. The compiler seems to prioritise the power two optimization (see the simpe shifts) instead of applying an expression equality check first. Since I doubt, clang lacks in expression equality checks in general even for older versions, I think it's not able to identify the equality right after the power two optimization (heavily further depends on involved registers).

Comment: Did you try replace unary minus with binary? It looks like it's what screws things up, x*b and (-x)*b  don't look equivalent after power of two optimization (can't optimize the second properly, UB)

Comment: Fixed in clang 10.0 and later: https://godbolt.org/z/5qTaEz

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Replacing unary minus with the equivalent `0-x` doesn't change clang's optimization: `(x * b) + ((0-x) * b)` gives the same asm https://godbolt.org/z/6bbYaY. Did you mean also changing the `+`, so it's `(x * b) - (x * b)` which is trivially easy for common-subexpression-elimination to optimize?  `-x*b` is `(-x)*b` as you pointed out, and requires the compiler to be smarter to see it's the negative of `x*b`.

Comment: Can anyone point which pass this refers to?

Answer (score 2):

It is an optimization problem in Clang, which was fixed after version 10.0.0.
We can reproduce this problem in version 9.0.1.

Compared versions 9.0.1 and 10.0.0 in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xee3zc1bj).